# How to post HTML5 fileEntry file to .net core web api?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, asp.net-core, upload

I'm playing with Chrome extensions. My extension have one simple popup with a button that read a file from Chrome FileSystem and POST this file to a .net core WebAPI.

```
function requestUpload() {
  window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 5 * 1024 * 1024,
    function (fs) {
      fs.root.getFile('ciccio.txt', {}, function (fileEntry) {

        // Get a File object representing the file,
        fileEntry.file(function (files) {

          let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("post", "http://localhost:5000/api/Files/UploadFiles", true);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", files.name);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", files.size);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", files.type);
          xhr.send(files);
        }, errorHandler);

      }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
}
```

My WebAPI action is following:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile files)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Uploading the file I obtain this exception:

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Missing content-type boundary.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try using FormData: [sending a file as multipart through xmlHttpRequest](//stackoverflow.com/a/9397172)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getFile() call to get the file ,returns a File Object.

```
fs.root.getFile('ciccio.txt', {}, function (fileEntry) {
```

[XMLHttpRequest.send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) has the following overloads :

```
void send();
void send(ArrayBuffer data);
void send(Blob data);
void send(Document data);
void send(DOMString? data);
void send(FormData data);
```

[File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object is of type Blob only,so it should also work.But it looks like [asp.net core may not work](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/433), [this](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/433) ,[this](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/191) correctly if you do not set the Content Type header with correct boundary.I think using formdata will work correctly.

Please try  following and you do not need to set the multipart content type header

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);
xmlHttpRequest.send(formData);
```